# Django bulk create for models with multiple required fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Person` model, a `Demographic` model, and a `PersonDemographic` model which contains detailed methods using data from both models, and saves some very expensive calculations as a field for specific person-demographic instances. How do I use bulk create to facilitate entries into my `PersonDemographic` model?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    details = a bunch of fields ...

class Demographic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    details = a bunch of fields ...

class PersonDemographic(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    demographic = models.ForeignKey(Demographic)
    expense_calc_property = models.FloatField(null=True)

    @property
    def random_property(self):
        calc using person/demographic details

    @property
    def expense_calc(self):
        if not expensive_calc_property:
           self.expensive_calc_property = results from expensive calc
           self.save()
        return self.expensive_calc_property
```

So how do I use `PersonDemographic.objects.bulk_create([])` for a large query set, such as `Person.object.some_query_set()` matched up with a single demographic instance, say `demographic = Demographic.objects.get(id=7)`? In other words, something which replaces:

```
demographic = Demographic.objects.get(id=7)
for person in Person.objects.some_query_set():
    pg = PersonDemographic.objects.create(person=person, demographic=demographic)
    pg.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
demographic = Demographic.objects.get(id=7)
PersonDemographic.objects.bulk_create(
    [PersonDemographic(person=person, demographic=demographic) for person in Person.objects.some_query_set()]
)
```